# Find a value within array objects and use another value from that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can't find a the correct workflow to get the following from looping thro array:

- loop thro all the objects within the array and find a specific `warehouse` value
- if the value exists in any object, use that object which holds the specific `warehouse` value and return a `price` value within it

For example: If I would do a search for `1374610389` warehouse value I would get returned price of `78.00`

```js
var test = [
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "10.00",
    warehouse: 1157964289
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "22.00",
    warehouse: 1269753487
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "78.00",
    warehouse: 1374610389
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "32.00",
    warehouse: 1674985630
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "16.00",
    warehouse: 1847893458
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = [{
  lorem: "ipsum",
  dolor: "sit",
  price: "10.00",
  warehouse: 1157964289
}, {
  lorem: "ipsum",
  dolor: "sit",
  price: "22.00",
  warehouse: 1269753487
}, {
  lorem: "ipsum",
  dolor: "sit",
  price: "78.00",
  warehouse: 1374610389
}, {
  lorem: "ipsum",
  dolor: "sit",
  price: "32.00",
  warehouse: 1674985630
}, {
  lorem: "ipsum",
  dolor: "sit",
  price: "16.00",
  warehouse: 1847893458
}];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  if (test[i].warehouse == 1374610389) {
    console.log(test[i].price);
  }
}
```

Get the length of the array using the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) propertie and enumerate over it using a `for`.

Also check Zakaria Acharki answer, his is way more elegant.

Comment: one quick question - can i use regex matching with this statement? For example: if warehouse contains first two numbers?

Comment: @g5wx warehouse is a number and I'd be really surprised to find out that regex work on numbers, but you could do something like ```test[i].warehouse.toString().match(expr)``` where ```expr``` is your regular expression, but I haven't really used regEx in javascript so not really sure

Answer (score 2):

> The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

You could use the **[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method :

```
test.find(obj => obj.warehouse == '1374610389').price
```

```js
var test = [
    {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "10.00",
    warehouse: 1157964289
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "22.00",
    warehouse: 1269753487
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "78.00",
    warehouse: 1374610389
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "32.00",
    warehouse: 1674985630
  },
  {
    lorem: "ipsum",
    dolor: "sit",
    price: "16.00",
    warehouse: 1847893458
  }
]

console.log( test.find(obj => obj.warehouse == '1374610389').price);
```

Comment: OP said **if the value exists in any object**, use that object,